# jQuery hover problem with nested lists in ie7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, hover, nested-lists

I've got a a left floated UL list for a menu, one option with a nested UL for dropdown, each of which is given it's own nested ul child, which is only displayed on hover. What I'm finding in IE 7 is that if the mouse moves out of the boundries of the parent then the sub-menu disappers, it also seems to be clearing out the links in the submenu as well.

Current page can be found at http://evolutionmmo.co.uk/WLT/. The item with the dropdown is "Planning Your Trip".

I'm thinking this may be a positioning css issue with my menus, but can't figure it out.

UPDATE:

Ok, after some fiddling around, I seem to have discovered some rather odd behaviour with my menus. First off, if you attempt to mouse over an item above it, it will just hid the menu, Secondly if you attempt to move from one item to another in the sub sub menu, and you are not moving from an area with text to an area with text, that is, not mousing over the words, rather the white space to the side, then it will hide the menu as well, and I can't for the life of me figure out why this is happening. This is still only in IE7.

Thanks, Psy

Comment: It's almost certainly a positioning issue, I've not got IE7 on this system so can't test but are there any gaps between your dropdown elements?

Comment: No, not that I can see anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I feel so stupid on this one.

I'd forgotten to apply a width to the containing UL >.<

Giving that the same width as the LI's sorted it out perfectly

Comment: my word! it worked ... thank you for answering your question. I was soooo confused as to why i was having this problem! +1 :D